# Firefox-Quantum-compatible extension for directly saving links to Google Drive

Tags: firefox, google-drive

I would like to find a Firefox-Quantum-compatible extension that allows you to directly add files from links to Google Drive without first downloading them to the local computer and then manually uploading them again.

All of the feature set of the now abandoned https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/save-to-google-drive/ add-on are what is desired. The list of features from that add-on is below are what is desired:

1. Save entire files to your Google Drive account just by providing a link or selecting a link from the page you're browsing.
2. Save Images to your Google Drive account easily. Right click image, Save Image to Google Drive, Done.
3. Links are added in a queue and are processed one by one. Queued links are saved persistently, so that you don't lose any of your links in case of browser restart.
4. Add the link in Clipboard to queue by a single click
5. Analyze all the links/images in the current page, select only those you want to be saved, and all the files in those links will be in your Google Drive account the very next moment.
6. Fully customize the notification settings (Login Failure/Invalid Link/Save Successful) according to your preferences.
7. All files are saved under the root dirctory of your Google Drive account. You can later download all files together as a zip from Google Drive using its options. To do that, in Google Drive select all the files you want to download as a zip, right click and select Download

One 2018-08-24, I looked at https://alternativeto.net/software/save-to-google-drive/ and found no alternatives.

Comment: Would love to have something like this too...